# Is there something similar to the OEIS wiki page on mathematical symbols for vanilla LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, blackboard

The The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS) maintains a [wiki-page](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols) describing how to produce various mathematical symbols in LaTeX. However, several of the OEIS commands are custom defined. For example, they say that the symbol for the real numbers (ℝ) can be produced by writing `$\R$`. However, doing that will result in an error unelss you import a package or define a new command. In "vanilla" LaTeX, blackboard-bold ℝ is often achieved by writing `$\mathbb{R}$` To get the [OEIS wiki code](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols) to work, you have to write something like `\newcommand\R[...]`

Is there a webpage similar to the OEIS wiki page on mathematical symbols for vanilla LaTeX? When I say a "vanilla" copy of LaTeX, I mean an unmodified copy of LaTeX. The Vanilla distribution of LaTeX might have some additional libraries if those libraries are standard or very popular. However, we don't define any new commands inside of our document or import any esoteric packages having fewer than two dozen users.

Comment: have you tried `texdoc symbols-a4`

Comment: Tout concept of "Vanille LaTeX" is somehow odd. LaTeX is a set of TeX macros offering some high level functions for formatting a document, but does not provides a lot of symbols. They are provided by standard packages  coming usually with the compiler in a so called "TeX distribution" . They are actually listed,  classed by type and by package in the symbol-a4 file suggested by the previous comment.